# I Can't Install opencv python3.8

Tags: python, opencv, pip

```
[cnahl@localhost ]$ pip install opencv_python-3.4.11.43-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl 
Processing ./opencv_python-3.4.11.43-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
```

---

```
ERROR: Wheel 'opencv-python' located at /home/cnahl/文档/opencv_python-3.4.11.43-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is invalid.
```

I tried installing `opencv` using the `pip install opencv`, but I got this error code instead. I'll really use y'alls help. Python is 3.8. I'm sure the file in this path exists.

Comment: The wheel file seems to be corrupt. Did you try to download the wheel from other locations or to install other similar wheel files? What was the outcome?

Comment: it seems you have to download wheel again. OR maybe this is not version for your system/CPU.

Comment: is this FULL error message? Maybe there are other useful information in FULL error message.

Answer (score 0):

pip install opencv-python==3.4.11.43

Seems to me a good alternative.

Comment: This is a contest that requires the package to be installed only via local.I don't know the reason for this error, but this file does exist in this path